# Move Panel Right and Left with button Click C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, move

I'm using WinForms. In my Form I have a Panel with buttons that move the panel. For example the Up and Down button move the panel up or down. I'm having difficulties moving the panel left and right with the corresponding buttons. What i'm i doing wrong?

```
    private void Up_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Location.Y > -2000) 
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y - 80);        
        }
    }

    private void Down_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Location.Y < 720) 
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y + 80);
        }
    }

    private void Left_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.Y , panel1.Location.X + +55);             
        }
    }

    private void Right_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.Y, panel1.Location.X -55);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: In your last 2 locations the order of x and y is incorrect.

Comment: this line panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.Y , panel1.Location.X + +55); there is double `+` sign there.

Comment: The problem is when i click on the right button the panel doesn't move right or when i click on the left button the panel doesn't move left. It moves side ways. @RezaAghaei

Comment: Thanks every body for the help!

Comment: You are welcome :) Also if you are using up criteria with `>-y` and down with `<y`, probably you need such logic for left and right `>-x` and `<x`

Comment: @taji01 you are welcome. Glad that the answers can be of any help for you. As I mentioned in the answer, we know we did spoil our math test at one time or another due to this issue too.. ;)

Comment: aah Thanks for catching that! @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Yes, I know that we *did* spoil our math tests at one point or another due to coordinate issue!)

**Problem**

`Point()` is always (x,y) coordinate. In your code:

```
private void Left_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.Y , panel1.Location.X + +55);             
    }
}

private void Right_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.Y, panel1.Location.X -55);
    }
}
```

You put X coordinate with Y value and vice versa.

Side note: there is a double `+` in your left button click event too..

**Step 1**

First, do the reverse:

```
private void Left_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + 55 , panel1.Location.Y);             
    }
}

private void Right_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X - 55, panel1.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

Secondly, see if left and right is what you intended. Note that moving left means we decrease our X and moving right we increase our X.

Should it not be done this way?

```
private void Left_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //The name is Left
{
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X - 55 , panel1.Location.Y);             
    }
}

private void Right_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //The name is Right
{
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + 55, panel1.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: The double + is not a problem since it means the number is positive.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Yes, it is just a side note.

Comment: Using `panel1.Location.X + 55` Your left button moves the panel to right!

Answer (score 6):

In your last 2 methods, the order of x and y is incorrect.

To move left, you should decrease `X`:

```
panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X - 55, panel1.Location.Y);
```

To Move right, you should increase `X`:

```
panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + 55,  panel1.Location.Y , );
```

I also guess if you are using up criteria with `>-y` and down with `<y`, probably you need such logic for left and right `>-x` and `<x`.

Answer (score 4):

You mixed the coordinates:

```
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.Y , panel1.Location.X + 55);             
    }
```

should be

```
    if (panel1.Location.X < 720) 
    {
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + 55, panel.Location.Y);             
    }
```

And the same for the left button.